# How to get the child state data back to parent

Tags: reactjs

In my react project, I have been developing my child components all the way until now. In child, it has its own state, and its state is a state of obj with a very long and complicated key value pair. And in it, its state have been referencing here and there.

At some point, in the parent, I need to have a button to gather all child's state data, for some aggregation.

To do that, I know I can reinvent everything again, I can do prop drilling from parents and let not child have it own state, and once the child call set function, Parent can have every child state.

The problem is that Child components has been developed for long, so I dont want to change its structure.

**Q:** Simply put, without removing child state and re create state from parent, How can I get all child state data from parent easily?

To better illustrate it, below is a simply example code that can be enough to explain the problem

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export function App(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <Child name="child1"></Child>
        <Child name="child2"></Child>
        <Child name="child3"></Child>
      </div>
      //Later at some point, I need to aggreate back all the data in child for aggreate action.
      <div>
        <button>Print out all the state data in children</button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

const Child = (props) => {
  const { name } = props;

  const [data, setData] = useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={(e) => setData(e.target.value)}></input>
      <p>
        Input in {name}: {data}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: You have a couple options: (1) add state to the parent and pass a callback function to each child so that the child can update the parent on state changes, or (2) use a state management library like redux, recoil, mobx, etc.

Comment: In addition to what @Ezra mentioned there is the (3) React Context API.
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: As my understanding, use Context could only pass parent data down to child, or it means it is a gobal state. However, the data I want is in child state. How can I get it back to parent by use context ? May I ask if you could provide a examples according to me example?

Comment: I dont want to move the state structure in child components, as child components have been developed very long time ago... I just want to access the state data in chid from parent. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a demo of the Context API.
It's a simple 3x3 Tic-Tac-Toe game. The state flow is explained in the comments.

```
let GameContext = React.createContext()

function Square({row, column}) {
    let context = useContext(GameContext);
    // here the child sets the state of the parent using setLetter
    // that was passed to child through the context
    return <div onClick={(evt)=>{context.setLetter(row,column)}}>
               {context.board[row][column]}
           </div>;
}

class Board  {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            board: Array.from({length:3},()=>Array.from({length: 3})),
            turn: 'O',
            // a method to update the state, is present in the state itself
            // & is passed to children through context
            // calling this method allows the child to update state of parent
            setLetter: (row,column)=> {
                this.setState((prevState)=> ({
                    board: prevState.board.map((line,r)=>(
                               line.map((lett,c)=> (
                                   (row==r && column == c)?prevState.turn:lett
                               )
                           ),
                    turn: (prevState.turn=='O')?'X':'O'
                });
            }
        };
    }
    
    render() {
        // the parent passes the state to the child through the context
        return <GameContext.Provider>{(value)=> {
            value.board.map((line,r)=>(
                line.map((lett,c)=> (
                    <Square row={r} column={c} />
                ))
            )
        }}</GameContext.Provider>;
    }
}
```

Fore more details on the Context API, this is a [good article](https://telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/react-hooks-guide/) that explains well.

Comment: May i ask if you have functional componet version instead of class component? Sorry that I dont understand this

Comment: I understand you are using another example to illustrate the context, but if possible, may you base on my code example for using context/redux?

Comment: function component should be practically the same with `useState` containing the initial state including `setLetter`. In class components, updating multiple state properties simultaneously is easier.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know Redux. It's a separate library.

Comment: In function components, you still have to pass the state to the Context Provider.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get back data from the child states. In order to achieve this feature, you must either pass props to the child component from the parent component or use the redux.  If you do not want to use both redux and pass props to the child component, we can use local storage or session storage. You just have to set the child's states in the local or session storage using the useEffect hook with the state dependency. When you click the button on the parent component, get the data from local or session storage back and use them as per your requirement. But this is a very bad idea. we should use  state management libraries like redux or context api.

Comment: To use context , does it mean that I need to remove the state from child. And then create a state in parent for child to update/access it ?

Comment: Or if possible, may I ask for an example of how to use redux to achieve this? simply put according to me code example?

Comment: "There is no way to get back data from the child states" - not true at all. See: React.forwardRef, React.useImperativeHandle, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without using Context api or state libraries like Redux, Mobx etc.

Here is an example.

This child component has a local state object called `user`. You can imagine there might be some logic (NOT shown here) that would change that state (eg. like an input that would allow updating the email).

To tell the parent that this state changed, we have a callback function `sendDataToParent` which is passed in as a prop.

When the button is clicked, we call that function and pass the current state object `user`

*Child.js*

```js
    import React from 'react'

    const Child = (props) => {
      const user = {
        name: 'Lisa Parker',
        email: 'lisa@gmail.com',
      }

      const onClick = () => {
        props.sendDataToParent(user)
      }

      return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={onClick}>Click Here</button>
        </div>
      )
    }
    export default Child
```

You then use the above like this:

```js
      <Child sendDataToParent={receivedDataHandler} />
```

The handler is the function that then handles the received data. You could, for example, simply put that received data into the parent's state, like so:

*Parent.js*

```js
    import React, { useState } from 'react'
    import Child from './components/Child'

    function Parent() {
      const [data, setData] = useState({
        name: '?',
        email: '?',
      })

      const receivedDataHandler = (data) => {
        setData(data)
      }

      return (
        <div className="App">
          <h2>Pass Data From Child to Parent Component</h2>
          
          <Child sendData={sendData} />
          <div>
            The user data sent from Child component:
            <strong>{data.name + ' : ' + data.email}</strong>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }

    export default Parent
```